# undefined method `to_a' for "include Rubeus::Swing\n":String

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jruby

I installed rubeus using the command below:

```
jruby -S gem install rubeus
bundle install
```

Then when i execute:

```
include Rubeus::Swing
```

I get this error :

```
undefined method `to_a' for "include Rubeus::Swing\n":String
```

So I think gem installed the wrong version, because method to_a is no longer supported in Ruby 1.9.x for strings

How can I fix this?

---

code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'java'
require 'rubeus'

include Rubeus::Swing #it's where everything crashes :-)
```

---

**UPDATE**

It seems the problem is with the jirb, I saved the code in a file and ran the code with jruby, and everything went well... I'm confused, what's wrong with jirb?

Comment: Are exactly you executing the include command?

Comment: yes i'm executing the include command

Comment: Sorry, I meant where exactly?

Comment: in jirb, after requiring rubeus
i mean the main block

Comment: Can you post the whole commands and output please? I don't get why your the include line should be converted into an array.

Comment: ok, i'll edit the question

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why, but I can confirm that Rubeus breaks jirb:

```
$ irb-jruby-1.7.3
irb(main):001:0> require 'rubeus'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> 1
NoMethodError: undefined method `to_a' for "1\n":String
```

Things do seem to work fine when non-interactively interpreting a script.  One workaround is to simply add `to_a` back into `String`:

```
class String
  def to_a
    lines.to_a
  end
end
# => nil
require 'rubeus'
# => true
include Rubeus::Swing
# => Object
```

The only issue I've noticed so far is that `require 'rubeus'` still breaks jirb in a second way: I now need to press Enter twice for every input.

Comment: I have to enter twice too... weird :D